# How to deploy chat server on heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, deployment, socket.io

So I've just created simple chat app with React, NodeJS, Express.JS and SocketIO. I'm going to deploy it on Heroku.

The problem is I'm not sure could I run both frontend and backend on the same URL. When I first created this chat locally, I've run front-end on localhost:3000 (default by Create-React-App) and backend on localhost:8000.

For the front-end side, I did it like this in external API.js file:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket;

export const api = {
  open: () => {
    socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
  }
}
```

For the backend side, I did it like this:

```
let express = require('express');
let io = require('socket.io')(8000);
```

So, you see, they're both on different ports. On my computer, it works perfectly. I'm not sure they could work locally on the same port (if I'm trying to switch 8000 port on back-end side to port 3000 it unfortunately doesn't work correctly - front and backend can't work on the same port, HTTP 404 error occurs).

My question is: is there any reason/is it even possible to put it on the same port? Because here's the problem number 2:

I've tried to deploy it on heroku, for the front-end side I've used Heroku Buildpack for create-react-app and it works fine, but totally don't know how to use it to deploy server-side. Should I create separate heroku address for the backend? And, at the code above, change paths like:

```
let socket;

export const api = {
  open: () => {
    socket = io('http://myherokuaddress');
  }
}
```

and

```
let express = require('express');
let io = require('socket.io')(http://myherokuaddress);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In heroku you can't define port manually. use this code instead of port 8000.

```
process.env.PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Zenith said, however, the best practice is to use different servers for frontend and backend code, that way you can build mode frontend apps that uses the same backend code. And, if for some reason, your frontend server is down, you will only need to host the frontend code anywhere else and still using the same backend.

Comment: So it works just like I said in bottom part of my post, isn't it? And can I deploy both (front and backend) on one-time, in one folder project?

Comment: I think you can, however, you can't use the ports that you want on heroku and that's why your code isn't working. You must use the process.env.PORT because that's the port that heroku gives you permission to use